# I want to show that for every $a>0$ there exists and $x$ st $\exp(- (x -a)^2 ) + \exp(- (x +a)^2 ) \ge 1 +\exp(- 4 a^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Consider the following inequality:
$$\exp(- (x -a)^2 )  + \exp(- (x +a)^2 )  \ge  1 +\exp(- 4 a^2)$$

Our goal is to show that for every $a>0$, there exists an $x$ such that this inequality is *strict.*

I did quite a bit of numerical simulation, and I can always find such an $x$.  This $x$ is always the maximum of $\exp(- (x -a)^2 )  + \exp(- (x +a)^2 ) $.

However, finding the maximum in closed-form seems difficult.

Comment: I slighter simpler equivalent formulation could be: for every $a>0$ the equation (with equality instead of $\ge$) has at least one root.

Comment: $x=a$ works, right?

Comment: YOu're right. @Boby I guess you mean that you want to prove that the _strict_ inequality holds? Elsewhere, it's trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, for a fixed $a$:

$$g(x) = \exp(- (x -a)^2 )  + \exp(- (x +a)^2 )  -  1 -\exp(- 4 a^2)$$

We have $g(a)=g(-a)=0$. Hence the inequality indeed holds (with the equality).

If we want to prove that the inequality holds strictly, then it's enough  to show that $g'(a) \ne 0$ - which is true if $a\ne 0$.